# Confused of mysql query whitespace values

Tags: mysql

I found a phenomenon of mysql, see below

```
insert into t(phone) select '12345   ';#tail with 3 white spaces
insert into t(phone) select '12345';
select * from t where phone = '12345'; #all can query out
+----------+
| phone    |
+----------+
| 12345    |
| 12345    |
+----------+
select phone, length(phone) from t where phone = '12345';
+----------+---------------+
| phone    | length(phone) |
+----------+---------------+
| 12345    |             8 |
| 12345    |             5 |
+----------+---------------+
select version();
+-----------------------------+
| version()                   |
+-----------------------------+
| 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log |
+-----------------------------+
```

That is even you query no white space value explicitly still could get with white space value out.
So why is this? is it a bug?

Comment: And [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) : `In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator: SELECT 'a' = 'a ', 'a' LIKE 'a ';`

Comment: I think you are right.